Why is "davon" used here? What's the meaning of it?
Ich habe eine andere Vorstellung davon, was wir machen sollen.

Looking at the accepted answer I guess, that you were not asking for the meaning of davon, but how the meaning of the sentence would change if it were omitted.  Unfortunatley the question lacks any details confirming that direction.

"da-words" (actually there is no other name for those) are often used as so-called Korrelat (correlate). Consider a simple sentence:

Er hat eine Vorstellung vom Leben.

"Vom Leben" here is a simple Objekt in Dativ case. But sometimes what is supposed to go into an Objekt is too big or complicated for a simple word or even phrase, so that they don't fit into a single Objekt:

Er hat eine Vorstellung vom [wie das das Leben verlaufen sollte].

For this there are Relativsätze: part sentences, where a part of the main sentence is deposited. This is fine, but now in the main sentence there is a part missing - the one, where the left out part should go. The Korrelats role is to mark this place where the content of the Relativsatz is to be included:

Er hat eine Vorstellung davon, wie das das Leben verlaufen sollte.

This "davon" basically means: read the content of the Relativsatz and use it as if it would be an Objekt at exactly the position where the "davon" stands.
The correct "da-word" is always "da"+ the preposition used. Because "vom" (which is a ontraction of "von dem") it is "davon". Would it be "aus", like e.g.:

Ich schließe aus deinem Schweigen, daß es stimmt.

it would be "daraus":

Ich schließe daraus, daß Du nichts gesagt hast, daß es stimmt.

Notice, that "da-words", regardless of being used as Korrelate or not, only work for things, not for people:

Der Sommer kommt. Ich träume davon. (correct)
Das ist meine Mutter. Ich träume davon. (WRONG!)
Das ist meine Mutter. Ich träume von ihr. (correct)


Forms like "davon" are combinations of a preposition and a pronoun, hence "davon" = "von dem".
In your example, you use the pronoun part ("da-" = "das") because you are signalling that a subordinate clause will follow, but this clause is shifted out of the core area of the clause and to the end (Nachfeld) -- compare the clearer variant:

"Er wird eine andere Vorstellung da- von gehabt haben ... was er machen soll"

And you also need the "von" because this is how the clause depends on "Vorstellung". This combines to "davon".
